# How to apply laplacian to every image in a folder

Tags: python, opencv

I have multiple images in a folder that I want to process and apply some OpenCV functions to them.
I am trying to find a laplacian for every image present in the folder, but I am able to process one at a time.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('xyz.jpg',0)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code can be refactored into a function, and you loop the function over multiple filepaths.

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def process(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath, 0)

    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
    

for filepath in Path("path/to/images").glob("*.jpg"):
    print(f"Processing {filepath}")
    process(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is using for loop

```py
import os
from glob import glob

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
IMGS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, '*.jpg')

for path in glob(IMGS_PATH):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    # processing
```

This probably is not the most efficient method if you have a really large amount of data, in that case, I would probably look for a library that does parallel image loading like Keras.